# how to set the restrictions for file upload in electron

Tags: c#, electron, electron-builder, microsoft-file-explorer

I am loading asp.net web application(not developed by me) inside electron and there is upload and download. I want to set the restriction which is the user can select the file from only one folder and can't browse to any folder location, can't type in file explorer address bar and can't click folder up level button.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrEgI.jpg)

Or
Is there a way to run background like windows service to control windows explorer?

Comment: Your application essentially runs inside a browser. Website code can't restrict the user's usage of their file system.

Comment: If you had access to the ASP.NET code, the html can be enhanced to filter the All Files extension with more specificity like so...

 `<input accept="audio/*|video/*|image/*|MIME_type" />`

Comment: Can we implement windows services running background to control windows explorer? when the user is using electron app?